# How to colorize a string with hex colors in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, hex

I'd like to extract hex colors from a string and generate a colored html code. Example: I have this string :

`#ff0000He#ffccccllo`

it'd convert it to

`<span style="color:#ff0000">He</span><span style="color:#ffcccc">llo</span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it using 'split' with a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Something like:

```js
var str = '#ff0000He#ffccccllo#123123sdfsdfsdfsdf#AA6456asdasdasd';
var expR = /(#[0-9|a-f]{6})/gi
var a = str.split(expR);
a.shift();

var output = ''
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   var color = a[i];
   var text = a[++i];     
   output += '<span style="color: ' + color + '">' + text + '</span>';
   
};
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Single-liner with regex replace:

```
"#ff0000He#ffccccllo#ffccccooo".replace(/(#.{6})([^#]*)/g, '<span style="color: $1">$2</span>')
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/c22a7vvd/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
var input = '#ff0000He#ffccccllo'.split('#');
var output = '';
input.filter(function (str) {
  return !!str;
}).forEach(function (str) {
  output += '<span style="#' + str.slice(0, 6) + '">' + str.slice(6) + '</span>';
})
console.log(output) // --> <span style="...
```

Or as a function:

```
function convert(input) {
   input = input.split('#');
   var output = '';
   input.filter(function (str) {
     return !!str;
   }).forEach(function (str) {
     output += '<span style="#' + str.slice(0, 6) + '">' + str.slice(6) + '</span>';
   })
   return output;
}
```

**UPDATE:** fixed error in the function dfn. Works now.